# Azure Devops yaml build definition PowerShell inline Syntax problem

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm working on a migration from the classic build system (task definition in Azure Devops) to a yaml build definition and running in the following error. I was able to break down the error while executing the PowerShell script and identfied a problem with the syntax in yaml file.

I use the PowerShell inline step like bellow:

```
name: 1.1$(Rev:.r)

jobs:
- job: build
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Test'
    inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '$var1 = "valueVar1" 
             $var2 = "valueVar2"'
```

When I run the command I#m getting the following error in Azure Devops.

```
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3306239Z At D:\A\01\_temp\298966df-c117-432b-b4c1-17b4ece9d7f4.ps1:2 char:21
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3306715Z + $var1 = "var1Value" $var2 = "var2Value"
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3306784Z +                     ~~~~~
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3306847Z Unexpected token '$var2' in expression or statement.
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3307001Z     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3307719Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
2019-12-07T18:39:15.3308055Z  
2019-12-07T18:39:15.4085556Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

It looks like that I connot use a line breaks in the yaml Powershell inline definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

should be done like so:

```
script: |
  $var1 = "valueVar1"
  $var2 = "valueVar2"
```

would work the same with any inline task (cmd\bash\pwsh).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example

in fact you can just do this:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    $var1 = "valueVar1"
    $var2 = "valueVar2"
```

Comment: This does not work. The script section can only execute batch and .CMD files. See the headline of your link. "Running batch and .CMD files". Execution result '$var1' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: nah, it works, just look at the schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet. I've used this zillion of times.